# Unable to load JSON file using AJAX:I have created a JSON file, and I am unable to load it using AJAX script. This is the code as below

Tags: json, ajax, xml, http

Below code is the script to pull details from JSON file: cars.json. checked everything but it doesnt seem to be loading in the webpage

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "./cars.json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                var carList = data.cars;
                var carHTML = ''; 

                for (var i = 0; i < carList.length; i++) {
                    carHTML += '<h2>' + carList[i].Brand + ' ' + carList[i].Model + '</h2>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Category:</strong> ' + carList[i].Category + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Availability:</strong> ' + (carList[i].Availability ? 'Available' : 'Not Available') + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Model Year:</strong> ' + carList[i]['Model Year'] + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Mileage:</strong> ' + carList[i].Mileage + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Fuel Type:</strong> ' + carList[i]['Fuel Type'] + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Seats:</strong> ' + carList[i].Seats + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Price/day:</strong> ' + carList[i]['Price/day'] + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<p><strong>Description:</strong> ' + carList[i].Description + '</p>';
                    carHTML += '<hr>';
                }

                $("#carList").html(carHTML);
            },
            error: function() {
            console.log("Error loading JSON file");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.